# Splash window breaks database filling

Tags: c#, database, wpf, entity-framework

Splash window breaks database filling. I have simple WPF form with label

```
public partial class SplashForm : Window
{
    public string StatusLabelText { get => lbLoadingStatus.Content.ToString() ?? ""; set => lbLoadingStatus.Content = value; }
    public SplashForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I have database context class with *Establishments* list also. It's EntityFramework technology.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Establishment> Establishments { get; set; } = null!;

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
        
    }
```

The *MainWindow* contains method, that fills database with one record.

```
public static void CheckDatabase()
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext dbC = ApplicationDbContext.GetContext())
        {
            var wtc = new WeekTimeConfiguration(StandartWeekHours.StandartHours.ToHoursString());
            var est = new Establishment()
            {
                Name = "Establishment 1",
                WeekConfiguration = wtc
            };
            dbC.Establishments.Add(est);
            dbC.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I invoke this method over another method in *MainWindow* constructor as follows:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

public void Initialize()
    {
        SplashForm splash = new SplashForm();
        splash.Show();

        splash.StatusLabelText = "Initialization of database";
        DBUtils.CheckDatabase();
        splash.Close();
    }
```

If I remove code linked with 'splash form', all will work well. On the other hand, if I will use presented full *Initialize()* method with 'splash form code' the record won't be added in database.
p.s. After inserting *Initialize()* method body into *MainWindow* contructor, all works well.
What's the possible reason of such strange behaviour of database filling?

Answer (score 0):

The probles was solved. I forgot remove action

```
Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

in ApplicationDbContext constructor. It recreated database and all changes at each Db modifying operation.